# Line numbers in .cs files but not in .aspx files within VS

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, editor, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional today. For some reason, I don't have line numbers in my view files, but I do have them in my .cs files. The option to turn line numbers on is selected in tools->editors->whatever.

I right clicked the project (asp.net Web Site), went to property pages, and looked at the debug output options, and noticed that it was being sent to a weird directory. I changed it to the bin folder of my current application, cleared temporary asp.net files, restarted VS2012, tried again, and no luck. Still the same symptoms.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

**Edit:** I just noticed after changing the debug output location that now, when I open up a `.aspx` file, VS freezes and becomes totally unresponsive.

Comment: When you created the project, did you choose New\Web Site or New\Project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each text editor has its own settings pane.

Are you changing the HTML editor settings?
Line numbers for ASPX files are enabled in the 
**Tools\Options\Text Editor\Html\General\Line Numbers** setting.

[image: Line Number Settings]

To enable settings for every editor window go to

**Tools\Options\Text Editor\All Languages\General\Line Numbers**.

Comment: I had it set to turn line numbers on in All Languages, but I had it off for html. Evidently the language-specific one overrides the general one. Thanks.

Comment: what a pita, should be a "turn on/off for all languages"
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Line numbers are not on by default.
To turn on line numbers just go to
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General -> Display and check Line numbers:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/07/turn-on-line-numbers-vstipedit0025.aspx

or you can toggle it for each language you want.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/TurnOnLineNumbering.aspx

Comment: I did enable that setting. The wording was a little iffy but I did say `"The option to turn line numbers on is selected in tools->editors->whatever."`